When can `T&`catch an exception but `T` not?
In MSVC, information about a throw expression is encoded by ThrowInfo.
struct ThrowInfo {
    unsigned int attributes;
    PMFN pmfnUnwind;
    int pForwardCompat;
    int pCatchableTypeArray; // RVA to the catchable type array
};

The catchable type array encodes which types can catch the thrown exception(e.g. base classes).
struct CatchableType {
    unsigned int properties;
    int pType;
    TypeDescriptor* pType;
    PMD thisDisplacement;
    int sizeOrOffset;
    PMFN copyFunction;
};

struct CatchableTypeArray {
    int nCatchableTypes;
    int arrayOfCatchableTypes[nCatchableTypes];
};

The properties flag of CatchableType consists of following flag bits:
#define CT_IsSimpleType 0x00000001 // type is a simple type
#define CT_ByReferenceOnly 0x00000002 // type must be caught by reference
#define CT_HasVirtualBase 0x00000004 // type is a class with virtual bases
#define CT_IsWinRTHandle 0x00000008 // type is a winrt handle
#define CT_IsStdBadAlloc 0x00000010 // type is a std::bad_alloc

What I don't understand is CT_ByReferenceOnly. If CT_ByReferenceOnly bit is set, catch blocks with non-reference parameter types are not matched. This makes catch(T& t) able to catch the exception but catch(T t) not. This behaviour can be observed by patching the binary. The following program must print Hello.
#include <cstdio>

struct A {};

int main() {
    try {
        try {
            throw A{};
        } catch (A a) {
            std::printf("Hello\n");
        }
    } catch (A& a) {
        std::printf("World\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

But if one manually sets CT_ByReferenceOnly bit on, it prints World.
Sure, for example if T is an abstract type, the programmer must catch with reference, or else the compiler will complain. But this is the compiler's job, and checking at runtime is unnecessary. Indeed in this case, CT_ByReferenceOnly bit is not set. Are there any examples where CT_ByReferenceOnly bit is set?

You should never catch a thrown object by value, only by reference or pointer. Also, int nCatchableTypes; int arrayOfCatchableTypes[nCatchableTypes]; is not valid C++, especially inside of a struct.

@RemyLebeau This is not a question about whether a programmer should catch with reference or not. And yes, it is not a valid C++, just a pseudocode.

@RemyLebeau Beware always/never rules. Imma gonna catch ints and char*s by value, if’n I ever throw them.

@HansPassant I've tried earlier but unfortunately noncopyable exceptions also didn't set the bit on

@Dúthomhas when I say "objects", I mean struct/class types, not trivial types.

I don't think there are any situations in the current standard's exception handling where an exception object type can only be caught by T&, but not T, except where T can already be known at compile-time of the catch handler to be unable to catch at all.

@user17732522 True, but Remy is right: you should catch exceptions by (const) reference.

@Dúthomhas Sure, but this question isn't about what the user should do. It is trying to reverse-engineer the reasoning for MSVC's exception handling mechanism. I am just saying that I can't find any justification for the CT_ByReferenceOnly field in the current standard rules. Maybe it is historical or for a MSVC-specific extension?

Are those C++ exceptions, or SEH exceptions?  (I think they are SEH.  Not 100% sure though.)

@Eljay The structures are for C++ exceptions

But MS supports SEH and something of their own as well
